# Can ds.record.getRecord('...') be read only?

Tags: deepstream.io

I can see that getRecord call has CREATEORREAD action. Is it possible to make it read only? I need it to properly limit client permissions.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to avoid creating it if user does not have permissions? If the user does not have permissions for UPDATE or PATCH this will stop him from being able to update anything, but we don't yet have an individual READ action to avoid the record from being created initially. We'll raise that as an issue and try implement it soon.

Edit:

Issue created on [github](https://github.com/deepstreamIO/deepstream.io/issues/123)